# Keeping raster table values in new vector file in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have calculated the time cost of a series of paths from prehistoric sites to their nearest water sources using the cost path tool.

I now want to convert the raster outputs I created to a vector polyline, but when I do, the new vector table doesn't keep the "PATHCOST" raster values and I am left only with the shape length.

I could copy the data I need manually, but I would have to do this hundred's of times.

How can I do this Automatically?

Comment: Why don't you convert it to polygons first? This way, values should be preserved.

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for your help. I tried that though, It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be setting the correct parameter for the Raster To Polyline tool.

If you read the [syntax section](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polyline.htm#GUID-65983674-0ADF-4DB3-BF28-5168AE710829) of the help file, the last parameter allows you to choose the field that will pass the cell values to the vector line.

Comment: I thought about this as well, but the "PATHCOST" field I need isn't available to choose from. I only have OBJECTID, Value, STARTROW, STARTCOL

Comment: I can only choose integer or string values, while the PATHCOST field is a float.

Comment: A simple trick is to create an integer field, multiply your float by x10 so your digits move to the left of the decimal point and the number can be stored in an integer field, then after processing divide it by x10.